# best way to write a-> ..->[a] recursive functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

So I keep having this small problem where I have something like

```
func :: a -> b -> [a]  -- # or basically any a-> ...-> [a] where ... is any types  ->
func x y = func' [x] y -- '# as long as they are used to generate a list of [a] from x

func' :: [a] -> b -> [a] 
func' = undefined -- # situation dependant generates a list from
                  -- # each element and returns it as one long list
```

should I keep it like this?

should I use func' hidden by a where?

should I only use the [a] -> b -> [a] version and leave the responsibility of passing [variable] to the callee?

I might well need to compose these functions and might want to mess around with the order so I'm leaning towards option 3. What do you think?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you give an actual example of where this is needed?

Comment: `func'`  reminds me of `(>>=)` and `(>>)`; `func x = func' [x]` or `func = func' . return`

Comment: Is your question about variable-length arguments to a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reinvent concatMap:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f = concat . map f
```

So the "map" bit takes each element of the input list applies "f" to it.  "f" takes a single "a" and returns a "[b]".  These individual lists are then concatenated into a single list.

Answer (score 2):

As [Paul noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003266/best-way-to-write-a-a-recursive-functions-in-haskell/3012442#3012442), `func'` can be replaced with `concatMap` and `func`.

And `func` itself reminds me of `unfoldr` [from Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html#v%3Aunfoldr):

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

It is used to generate a list of `a` from `b`.

By the way, `func` and `func'` are unfortunate names for such functions.